# $A$ is noetherian if and only if $A/\mathfrak{a}$ and $A/\mathfrak{b}$ are Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, quotient-spaces, exact-sequence, noetherian

Let $A$ be a ring e $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ two ideals, such that $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b} =(0)$. Prove that $A$ is Noetherian if and only if $A/\mathfrak{a}$ and $A/\mathfrak{b}$ are both Noetherian.

I was thinking about the following sequence:

$0 \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \overset{f}\rightarrow A \overset{v}\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{b} \rightarrow 0$.

$v$ is a quotient map, so it is surjective. Is it possible to find an injective function $f$ which makes this sequence exact? This way I could easily conclude.

Otherwise is there another way to solve this problem?
Thank you for you help.

Comment: There is, in general, no good map $A/\mathfrak a\to A$, unfortunately. For instance, see what happens with $A=\Bbb Z_6$, and the two ideals $(2)$ and $(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take two ideals $I\subseteq J$ in $A$ (such as in an ascending chain of ideals), and show that $I+(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})= J+(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})$ iff both $I+\mathfrak a= J+\mathfrak a$ and $I+\mathfrak b= J+\mathfrak b$.

Comment: $I_1+(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) = J + (\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) \iff I-J \subseteq (\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) \iff I-J \subseteq \mathfrak{a}  \wedge  I-J \subseteq \mathfrak{b} \iff [J]_{\mathfrak{a}} = [I]_{\mathfrak{a}} \wedge [J]_{\mathfrak{b}}= [I]_{\mathfrak{b}}$

Comment: @Phi_24 It's a bit difficult to read in a comment, but that looks fine. Except you may want $J\setminus I$ rather than $I-J$: The minus could be misinterpreted, and $J$ is the bigger ideal.

Comment: But $I-J = \{i-j | i \in I, j\in J\}$ is different from $∖ $. From $∖ \subseteq \frak{a}$ I can't conclude that $I$ and $J$ are in the same equivalence class. Right?

Comment: $I+(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) = J + (\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})$ doesn't say anything about $I-J$ and whether it's contained in $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ (consider what happens if $I,J$ are both larger than $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$). And yes, that's exactly what you can conclude. Under the assumption $J\subseteq I$, we get that $J\setminus I\subseteq \mathfrak a$ is equivalent to $I+\mathfrak a=J+\mathfrak a$. This might be easier to see in the special case $I=(0)$, and the isomorphism theorems tell you that any other case follows from there.